# Array broadcasting with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How do I write the following loop using Python's implicit looping?

```
def kl(myA, myB, a, b):
    lots of stuff that assumes all inputs are scalars

x, y = meshgrid(inclusive_arange(0.0, xsize, 0.10),\
                inclusive_arange(0.0, ysize, 0.10))

for j in range(x.shape[0]):
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        z[j, i] = kl(x[j, i], y[j, i])
```

I want to do something like

```
z = kl(x, y)
```

but that gives:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: "implicit looping"? can you define that?

Comment: I guess I meant "array broadcasting" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capability you're asking about only exists in Numpy, and it's called [*array broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting), not implicit looping. A function that broadcasts a scalar operation over an array is called a universal function, or ufunc. Many basic Numpy functions are of this type.

You can use [`numpy.frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) to convert your existing function `kl` into a ufunc.

```
kl_ufunc = numpy.frompyfunc(kl, 4, 1)
...
z = kl_ufunc(x + 1.0, y + 1.0, myA, myB)
```

Of course, if you want, you could call the ufunc `kl` instead of `kl_ufunc`, but then the original definition of `kl` would be lost. That might be fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a video series here which you might find useful:

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=10370070&fromSeriesID=1037

Note that it is part of a tutorial series that discusses a broad range of numpy topics.

Just FYI.