# Python decorator for simple recursion? In standard library or elsewhere?

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I'm looking for a Python decorator that can make a function recursive. I find myself writing a lot of functions like this:

```
def xyz(data):
    if not isinstance(data, TypeThatDenotesSingularity):
        return map(xyz, data)
    return singular_xyz(data)
```

I figure there must be a decorator out there somewhere (in the standard library?) that can slim down the notation a tad:

```
@recursive(TypeThatDenotesSingularity)
def xyz(data):
    return singular_xyz(data)
```

I have been searching but I can't seem to get anywhere. Perhaps I'm missing some essential terminology?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: +1 because I've seen myself write this kind of code way quite a few times. There are better ways to check for the base case though (e.g. a class Variable). I doubt there's anything in the stdlib though. Perhaps in functools... (Edit: checked it, not the case)

Comment: There are situations where this is the best option, but if I end up doing it, I've usually decided it's sloppy coding. Where the function is called, it should be unambiguous whether you've got a collection or a single item, so you write the appropriate code at that end. If something can be single or multiple, don't special case the single item, but have it in a collection of 1.

Comment: @Thomas K: I disagree. You are generalizing.

Comment: Numpy has a decorator for broadcasting on arrays, which might suffice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443234/array-broadcasting-with-numpy/3443301#3443301

Comment: @Tim: Well, yes. I said there are situations where it's useful, and maybe yours is one. But if you're finding that you have to do this a lot, it's worth considering that it's not the "one obvious way to do it". When I've found myself writing code like this, I've often realised there's a better way.

Comment: @Thomas: There are data structures that really want to be processed recursively - say, trees (XML).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
def recursive(stop_type):
    def _inner(func):
        def _recursive(data, *args, **kw):
            if not isinstance(data, stop_type):
                return map(_recursive, data)
            return func(data, *args, **kw)
        return _recursive
    return _inner
```

Explanation of how this works if used as `@recursive(MySingularType)`

1. recursive is called at function decoration time with the argument stop_type set to `MySingularType`
2. recursive returns closure `_inner`
3. `_inner` is immediately called with the function to decorate, also at compile time
4. `_inner` returns closure `_recursive` which is now the new function which is called when you call your decorated function

Now, when you call your function: `_recursive` is called. If the type matches, return the function result. Otherwise, map another call to _recursive, ad infinitum (well really ad until stackoverflowium)

**Note** You can omit the `*args` and `**kwargs` if the decorated function will always always only take a single value

Comment: Cool. But do you happen to know a library that contains one of those? I hate maintaining a proprietary utility belt.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno about a decorator, but you could do it with a class if you find yourself rewriting the same pattern over and over.

```
class Recursive(object):
    def __init__(self, check_type, singular):
        self.check_type = check_type
        self.singular = singular

    def __call__(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, self.check_type):
            return map(self, data)
        return self.singular(data)
```

Comment: You don't need a class. There are very few (rather complex) generators that justify a whole class. Most are written just fine as closures, including this one.

Comment: Class, closure, the difference is mostly in syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I could write one myself. But I'd much _much_ rather reuse some proven code than pile yet another chunk of liability onto my own heap.

Comment: @Tim: Ah, I missed that you were looking form something from a library. Bad reading comprehension. Bad!

Comment: I think you forgot the `self.singular = singular` in the `__init__`.